# how to put content in webkit column horizontally

Tags: css

how to put content in column horizontally like below,

```
(column1)  (column2)  (column3)
1.asd       2.asd      3.asd
4.asd       5.asd
```

this flow is required in the website

Comment: Have you tried something?? If yes, provide your code with the jsFiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

For columns in css3, you have to have a div structure for that...

**Html:-**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row">1</div>
        <div class="row">4</div>
        <div class="row">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row">2</div>
        <div class="row">5</div>
        <div class="row">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row">3</div>
        <div class="row">6</div>
        <div class="row">9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css:-**

```
.table { columns:3; -webkit-columns:3; -moz-columns:3; text-align:center }
.column { }
.row { background-color:red; }
```

**Demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/5P9c4/1/